# How to create piecewise linear and quadratic classifier

Tags: classification, references, pattern-recognition

Can someone suggests a literature that describe a procedure for projecting a piece-wise linear and piece-wise quadratic classifiers?

For example, let's say I have these classes:
[image]

How would I calculate optimal intersection point? I need the same of quadratic classifiers.

Comment: What kind of models are available for your use? To me, this is screaming out to use an SVM approach.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment! I actually need piecewise classifier exclusively.